# Converting Dot Decimal IP Address to Binary (Python)

Tags: python, binary, ip, ip-address, data-conversion

I need a program that would convert a user inputted IPv4 Address to a Binary and Base 10 Address. Something like this:

```
input: 142.55.33.1
output (base 10): [2385977601]
output (base 2): [10001110 00110111 00100001 00000001]
```

So far I have managed to convert it into a base10 address but I can't seem to get around the base 2 problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

ip_address = input("Please enter a dot decimal IP Address: ")

#splits the user entered IP address on the dot
ListA = ip_address.split(".")
ListA = list(map(int, ListA))

ListA = ListA[0]*(256**3) + ListA[1]*(256**2) + ListA[2]*(256**1) + ListA[3]
print("The IP Address in base 10 is: " , ListA)

#attempt at binary conversion (failing)
#ListA = ListA[0]*(2**3) + ListA[1]*(2**2) + ListA[2]*(2**1) + ListA[3]
#print("The IP Address in base 2 is: " , ListA)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `format`:

```
>>> text = '142.55.33.1'
>>> ' ' .join(format(int(x), '08b') for x in text.split('.'))
'10001110 00110111 00100001 00000001'
```

In case if you want a list:

```
>>> [format(int(x), '08b') for x in text.split('.')]
['10001110', '00110111', '00100001', '00000001']
```

Here format converts an integer to its binary string representation:

```
>>> format(8, 'b')
'1000'
>>> format(8, '08b')  #with padding
'00001000'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.format):

```
>>> ip_address = '142.55.33.1'
>>> ['{:08b}'.format(int(n)) for n in ip_address.split('.')]
['10001110', '00110111', '00100001', '00000001']
>>> ' '.join('{:08b}'.format(int(n)) for n in ip_address.split('.'))
'10001110 00110111 00100001 00000001'
```

Comment: ['{:08b}'.format(int(n)) for n in ip_address.split('.')] <-- could you kindly explain what's going on here?

Comment: @user1819786, `[... for item in seq]` is called [**list comprehension**](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: `str.format` is used to make a binary representation of the number. For example `'{:08b}'.format(3)` yields `00000011`. See [Format String Syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings).